Solving y = BX using Gram Matrix
To find regression coefficients in linear regression, BLUE estimator in particular, the formula seen below is a good estimator:
$$
B = (X^T X ) ^{-1}X^T y
$$
In this setting, y and X are known and B is unknown.
If y is in the column space of X, then B is the exact answer or otherwise approximate answer.
I was trying to see when the above formula is the solution and when it isn't in terms of The Gram-matrix $(X^T X ) $ and y. To me, it makes sense that whatever criteria that turn out to be the answer, should be about relationship of X and y. Any help is very appriciated
